# Side-by-side elements on large screens and centered on small screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can i display elements side-by-side on large screens, float left & right, and centered one above the other on small screens? If possible without media queries:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code;

```css
.abc {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
    <div>first element</div>
    <div>second element</div>
    <div>third element</div>
    <div>forth element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems to remain side-by-side on small screens

Comment: i juste tried, even on small screens the 2 inner divs remain side-by-side

Comment: This maintains the size of the elements on different devices.

Comment: Or simply go to the dev tools and decrease the size of the screen more and more and you will see that it works perfectly.

Comment: i just did it : https://i.imgur.com/AmhxpKN.png

Comment: Edited my answer. Check that out. Hope that helps. Please leave an upvote if it helps!